# Moved iPhoto Library: Need to point iMovie in the right direction

Tags: photos.app, imovie, ilife, macos

my friend has moved her iPhoto 08 Library from an external HD. She has some iMovie 08 projects which reference iPhoto movies.

How can I update iMovie to the new location of the iPhoto library. We no longer have access to the external HD.

Answer (score 1):

Locate the iPhoto library in Finder, drag and drop it to iMovie's project pane?

Comment: This works in part, iMovie now recognises the new library. Unfortunately the video references are still broken. Good try though.